# Physical device and emulator with same size UI not matching

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, samsung-galaxy

I am developing an Android app that comes preinstalled on a phone or tablet that we resell.
One of these devices is a Samsung Galaxy A21s. So I know a large portion of our users will use this specific device. To test small UI changes it is often easier to boot up the emulator instead of connecting the device.

So I know my device is this one https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a21s-10239.php which as you can see has screen size of 720 x 1600 pixels. I also validated this with adb

```bash
$ adb shell wm size
Physical size: 720x1600
```

So I configured an AVD in Android Studio with the above specifications.
[image: Android Virtual Device configuration screen]
Configuring the AVD also allows me to use it as preview when editing the layout.

However the preview and the emulator give a different result of the UI than the real device.
In the real device the images I lined up were very close together instead of more spaced out.
I used fixed dp values for the width and height since I know exactly which devices the app will run on and it was easier to modify this existing layout.

I doublechecked the settings and did not see anything that would affect the sizes. There was a zoom level in accessibility settings but it was set on the minimum value of 0.

How can I resolve this and make the emulator match the look of this device?
Is the AVD configuration bugged?
Is there something specific about this device that would make images seem closer together than the emulator?

Thank you for your answers!